# Flutter crashes on hot restart and throws Error 105 on hot reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I've been experiencing this only on ios emulator. Android works perfectly. 
When I run my app I get blank white screen, but no error in console.
But when I hot reload I got this:
[image]

When I hot restart the app crashes with:
[image]

I stumbled upon similar posts and some had to do with dependencies. Most specifically firebase_messaging, however I don't use the one. I do think it maybe has to do with my flutter_localization dependency, but when I tried to run the app without it, it didn't change anything. 
I also tried to change the channels and the app works on master channel but throws all sorts of other weird errors on both android and ios so I decided to stay on stable channel.

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # Localization
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.6.0
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.3
  firebase_database: ^3.1.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
  # Facebook Login
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  # Password Packages
  flutter_password_strength: ^0.1.4
  password_strength: ^0.1.2
  # Font Awesome
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.7.0
  # Image Picker
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  # Money Parser
  flutter_masked_text: ^0.7.0
  # Google Maps
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.25+2
  #Geocode
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  # Nanoid - ID generator
  nanoid: ^0.1.0
  # URL Launcher
  url_launcher: ^5.4.2
  # Charts
  multi_charts: ^0.2.0
  # Launcher Icons
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4
  # Flare Animations
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.3


dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.4.4
```

Comment: Did you add any new package and get this error ?

Comment: Yes, the localizations package, but I'm just not sure wether that would be it, since I got rid of it than I ```fluter clean``` and tried it again and had a same error.